# how to run pylance to find references?

Tags: mypy, pylance, language-server-protocol

Can I run pylance to find references programatically?

I know pylance is a language server as theoreticallty I can connect to pylance and extract references from a function call is invoked.

For example for the following code:

```
import os
from getpass import getpass
from GPT4Readability.utils import *
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources  


def generate_readme(root_dir, output_name, model):
    """Generates a README.md file based on the python files in the provided directory

    Args:
        root_dir (str): The root directory of the python package to parse and generate a readme for
    """

    # prompt_folder_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "prompts")
    # prompt_path = os.path.join(prompt_folder_name, "readme_prompt.txt")

    with pkg_resources.open_text('GPT4Readability.prompts','readme_prompt.txt') as f:         
        inb_msg = f.read()

    # with open(prompt_path) as f:
    #     lines = f.readlines()
    # inb_msg = "".join(lines)

    file_check_result = check_files_in_directory(root_dir)
```

Here I need to find out `check_files_in_directory` is defined in the `GPT4Readability.utils`.

I am stugglign to find this informaiton.

Comment: Different from other things you might use before, Pylance is strictly licensed to be used in VS context, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.vscode-pylance/license So if your goals differ, you have to use other language servers.

Comment: Other than jedi, can you please suggest other language server please?